# Equivalent command of chocolatey's "choco outdated" in conda to find out outdated conda packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

In chocolatey, this command can list out outdated packages;

```
choco outdated
```

What is the equivalent command in conda to list the outdated conda packages?

I am using python 3.8, anaconda 2020.07

Comment: try: `conda update --all --dry-run`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the hint provided in the comment by @cel, I will answer my own question.

The following command will do the trick;

```
conda update --all --dry-run
```

or

```
conda update --all -d
```

Running the command will show the output of what will be installed but not actually install it. This makes it safe from accidentally making undesired installation.

To actually do the installation, run `conda update --all`

Comment: This wont update to new major (and also minor?) versions. 1.2.3 wont be updated to 2.0.1 or even 1.3.0.